# Image overlay on SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift4

I am attempting to place an image over the bottom of the screen on SFSafariVC which will have buttons to interact with the device. I have added the SafariViewController with no problems but I don't know how to add the image, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("row selected: \(filteredTable[indexPath.row])")

    let selURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
    let selSite = SFSafariViewController(url: selURL!)

    present(selSite, animated: true, completion: nil)
    selSite.delegate = self as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate

}
```

code for reference

Comment: do you want to add image to hide SafariViewController actions?

Comment: I basically want to add a bar that will sit along the bottom of the screen over the top of the SafariViewController that will let the user copy coupons. It might cover the action bar at the bottom of the screen but I'm not planning on the user interacting with that bar at all. Perhaps the image could move with the action bar at the bottom to prevent it from being covered?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this solution is what you want but in some cases you have not access to view controller to add view, you could add your view to key window;

**UPDATE**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/") else {
            return //be safe
        }
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let image = UIImage(named: "img")
    let imgV = UIImageView(image: image)
    imgV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 30, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 30)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(imgV)
```

By this code the image shows over the safari view without need you do any action (Tested)

Comment: I just get "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'UIView'" that error when I attempt to add the code into the function

Comment: Managed to get it working but it isn't working over the top of the SFSafariViewController, it shows up when I hit done on the Safari View, any ideas?

Comment: I will update my answer, but about tap need to show image let me. check it

Comment: For some reason it's still not sat over the SafariView for me. It's still showing up after I close the SafariView

Comment: I have tested it, I have no idea about that reason